# can not start android studio Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

Tags: android, android-studio, filenotfoundexception

When I start Android Studio this problem was happened. I tried to re-install android studio, restart window, but It didn't work

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\sev_user\.AndroidStudio2.3\system\port (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.writeToFile(FileUtil.java:1285)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.writeToFile(FileUtil.java:1279)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.writeToFile(FileUtil.java:1264)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lambda$lock$1(SocketLock.java:156)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:180)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:129)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:296)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:124)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:91)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: you may want to add more info

Answer (score 0):

Delete port.lock file uinder C:\Users....AndroidStudio2.3\config\ 
And restart the android studio.
The file will be recreated on studio launch

And check for

C:\Users\sev_user.AndroidStudio2.3\system\port .if it is hidden make it visible and allow universal permission for the file

Hope these two steps may solve your problem

Comment: I just tried to delete port and port.lock file and changed the permission for the folder but this issue still happens :(

Comment: I deleted the folder.AndroidStudio2.3 and It worked.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear:

> C:\Users\sev_user.AndroidStudio2.3\system\port (Access is denied)

The account that launches Android Studio is missing the permissions necessary to access the required file. You should carefully check the NTFS permissions set on `C:\Users\sev_user\.AndroidStudio2.3\system\` and `C:\Users\sev_user\.AndroidStudio2.3\system\port`.

Answer (score 0):

happened to me too, 
solved it by Installing newer version of Java JDK.

Hope it works for you too :)